# How to connect database in helper file of codeigniter 3x?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have create a new project using **CI3x** and converted the same in **HMVC**
Now i have created one **helper** file and **autoload** the same. Also the database library is also autoloaded.

There is a function in which i am trying to insert some values in the database but is show *database error*
for for details have a look at the code and errors below

```
**helper code**
if (!function_exists('create_meta')) {
    function create_meta($data = array()) {
        $CI = &get_instance(); //$CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();
        if (is_array($data) && !empty($data) && array_key_exists('page_url', $data)) {
            $CI->db->insert("table_name", $data);
        }
    }
}

**Error 1**
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'load' of non-object

Filename: helpers/Utils_helper.php

Line Number: 518

Backtrace:

File: E:\wamp64\www\dda\apps\helpers\Utils_helper.php
Line: 518
Function: _error_handler

File: E:\wamp64\www\dda\apps\modules\admin\controllers\Category.php
Line: 161
Function: create_meta

File: E:\wamp64\www\dda\index.php
Line: 320
Function: require_once

**Error 2**

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function database() on null

Filename: E:\wamp64\www\dda\apps\helpers\Utils_helper.php

Line Number: 518

Backtrace:

File: E:\wamp64\www\dda\apps\modules\admin\controllers\Category.php
Line: 161
Function: create_meta

File: E:\wamp64\www\dda\index.php
Line: 320
Function: require_once
```

Kindly look into and let you me know if anyone of you have faced and resolved same kind of issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `$CI->load->database();` from your function, it will work properly if you
have already loaded the database library in `application/config/autoload.php`.

If you didn't autoloaded the database please modify this line in your function:

```
$CI->load->database();
```

To:

```
 $CI->load->library('database');
```

In case you didn't know how to load your database library automatically. Open the application/config/autoload.php file, `$autoload['libraries']` and add your library like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: I have already loaded database in autoload.php, I am using PHP 7.3.12 and wamp server for localhost.

Comment: Ok, then just remove the line $CI->load->database();

Comment: No
when i removed $CI->load->database();
it gives me this error

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'db' of non-object

Filename: helpers/Utils_helper.php

Comment: please put space between & and get_instance. Like this & get_instance();

Comment: Same error
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'db' of non-object

Filename: helpers/Utils_helper.php

Actually i have tried most of the things, but don't now why this is coming.

Comment: does your database loaded properly?

Comment: Add this line to your function $CI->load->library('database');

Comment: Yes, Database is properly working,
as, all other queries are working in controller and there is no issue, this is only in helper files

Comment: Now this

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'load' of non-object

Filename: helpers/Utils_helper.php

Line Number: 517

Comment: Seem nothing is working!

could this be coz of wamp server 3.2 where mysql port is 3308

Comment: No, if your controllers are interacting with the database, then there is no problem on wamp server. I actually tested the code of the helper on my windows machine and it worked.

Comment: what should i say :(

tried everything so far, no luck

Comment: Solved

Instance was not creating for some reason.
now its working fine, thanks.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Instance was not creating properly.

Comment: Ok, congratulations